# PSD file save layer as PNG addes noise to the image

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am working on corner point detection. I have a PSD file with 3 layers, I want to extract only 1 layer whose corners I want to extract.

1. Using psd-tool i extract the layer:

   ```
   if layer.name == 'Layer 3':
   img = layer.as_PIL().save("tmp.png")
   ```
2. Next I read the tmp.png file and do the following operations:

   ```
   img = cv2.imread(filename)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(gray, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
   cv2.imwrite('bw_image.png', im_bw)


   _ ,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

   contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea,reverse=True)[:1]

   cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 5)

   cv2.imwrite("image_processed.png", img)
   ```

But if I manually extract the layer and save it. The algo works fine and returns the 4 corner points.

Please suggest what might be wrong here.

Comment: when I do img.show() just after img = layer.as_PIL(). It shows Actual Image alog with garbage colors, instead of transparent.

Comment: wheere do you get this "psd-tool"?

Comment: i have downloaded this tool from https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwi-8PaKienGAhVHU44KHewhCOk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkmike%2Fpsd-tools&ei=vZOsVf6dPMemuQTsw6DIDg&usg=AFQjCNHiDvPPLMSJNN-kg96-wLPAoj6ZBQ&bvm=bv.98197061,d.c2E

Comment: You ara aware that your issues probably lie into this code, don't you? And that it is not widelly used as Pillow or opencv. You should at least add the `import` and how do you get to the  `layer` object on the first listing, instead of simply writting that in English. That should imporeve your chances of getting a significative answer here.

Comment: @jsbueno I have added import in the actual code. There are exactly 3 layers and I knw the name of layers before hand. Hence the image processing that i have to do is to be bone on Layer 1 only. The layers have a transparent background. But when I use img.as_PIL() and do a img.show() the displayed image shown has some noise or random colors at place where it should be transparent. But if i save this image as png and open it, it is displayed normally (with transparent background). Again when I open the saved image with PIL img.open(fileName) img.show() again has same noise in its background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood that if we display PIL image with transparent information, it is automatically displayed in BMP format. Hence, we have to paste a transparent layer to the actual image and then save it in correct format. PNG.